# azure - Autoscaling a VM with DB

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-vm-scale-set

Recently, I have been introduced to Azure and I have to replicate my network with VM. I have some doubts about the scaling. the documentation says:

> When you create a scale set, you define the number of VM instances that you wish to run. As your application demand changes, you can automatically increase or decrease the number of VM instances.

let's say I have VM with a DB on it when the autoscale trigger and switch on a new instance has that one the exact same DB? or could it create data to be not synchronized or not persistent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it just creates a new VM, its your duty to have scripts\external process to configure it. It wont come up with a DB (unless you are using a SQL image or something like that).

You would use VM Script extension or DSC extension or something else to configure the VM to join the DB cluster and sync data or something like that.